# End console app - File path is not showing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, console

I am trying to make a WPF application that can also be run from the command line. I have a WPF app that that I am able to achieve this to some extent with. It is possible to run with 0 arguments and a window will load.

When I run it with > 0 arguments the idea is to have it run from the command line and thus should print to the command line. So for this I have [Attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415807/output-console-writeline-from-wpf-windows-applications-to-actual-console) a console and then [Freed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160587/no-output-to-console-from-a-wpf-application) the console after I am done.

However the following results on the command line when everything is finished.

> I **am able** to run another command here but why isn't it displaying the full directory to make it clear that it has finished?
>
> Is there anyway this can be resolved?

[image: Command line output]

On further inspection I have noticed that it seems to be printing the new line before the output rather than after.

[image]

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool AttachConsole(int processId);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool FreeConsole();

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        if (e.Args.Length > 0)
        {
            AttachConsole(-1);
            Console.WriteLine("\nStart");
            Console.WriteLine("Stop");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            FreeConsole();
        }
        else
        {
            new MainWindow().ShowDialog();
        }
        this.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the AllocConsole function? I have always used it without any problem.

```
[DllImport("Kernel32")]
internal static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

Comment: So I have tried replacing the AttachConsole(-1) with AllocConsole() and the result is nothing it printed to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't do it that way.  What you need are 2 versions:

- app.exe
- app.com

if launched from the command line with command `app` then the .com will be preferentially executed.  This is a console app and if the input suggests that really the GUI should be launched then it launches the exe.  Otherwise it continues as a console app and does whatever it needs to.

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/junfeng/how-to-make-an-application-as-both-gui-and-console-application

This is what devenv does.