# Redirect start command from bat file

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to create a .bat file to make some tasks easier but i'm having troubles to redirect the Console output of my application (written in C#) to the console which execute my bat file.

In my program I just do :

```
Console.Writeline("some text");
```

Here is my bat file :

```
@echo

    start "" "Myapp.exe" "-t" "-n" 2> NUL


    pause
```

When I launch the bat file it just displays my command and "pause" but doesn't want to write all my lines.

Why ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Start command will execute your app in new console window. Probably you want to have your bat file like this

```
@echo

Myapp.exe -t -n 2> NUL

pause
```

Comment: This seems better (the console wait for my program to finish his task to display "pause", but still doesn't display any of my WriteLine

Comment: Is your output displayed, when you run your app from console manually?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be related to [Output Console.WriteLine from WPF Windows Applications to actual console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415807/output-console-writeline-from-wpf-windows-applications-to-actual-console).

Try `start /b /wait myapp.exe -t -n 2>nul` and see if that gives the output you want.