# Msgbox Wait until, VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to have a Msgbox without a button on it in a console application. I would like to have a msgbox pop up and then disappear when the task has been completed. Or could I send the msgboxresult to some form of window that would just disappear when the file has been written?

```
MsgBox("The users on the domain are being gathered. A prompt will appear when all information has been gathered.")
    Dim userFile2 As String = savefileDialog1.FileName & ".txt"
    Dim fileExists2 As Boolean = File.Exists(userFile2)
    Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(userFile2, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        For Each d As DirectoryEntry In de.Children()
            sw.WriteLine(d.Name)
        Next
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a console app with a GUI, I'd suggest that it might be easier to just make a WinForms app. Just create a new tiny WinForms app, make the default `Form` small as a dialog box and make it have only one invisible `Close` button.

Then you can just show the `Close` button when it's finished.

Just remember to disable the Control box on the `Form` (the X up in the top right hand corner) and handle any keyboard combination that could close it.

Edit: Or if for any reason you have to have it as a Console app, then you could still write a tiny separate app that just does the GUI part that you need and have the Console app start up the GUI app, sending over the text to display.

Comment: ... you forgot to mention that he should open the Form in a non-modal state.

Comment: Why use winforms in .Net 4.0?

Comment: @Jodrell: Most of my experience is in WinForms so I'd use that automatically for such a tiny app, since WPF or WinForms doesn't really make much difference for this.

Answer (score 1):

First, a quick point. A `MsgBox` is a modal dialog so will halt execution until the user responds, you can't use this.

In general "console" applications should be non-graphical.

You don't want to use a console application to disiplay a window. Since .Net 4.0 is available to you may want a WPF application that can write to the console.

There is a post about outputting to the console with WPF [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160587/no-output-to-console-from-a-wpf-application) on SO.

You should do your work on a different thread perhaps using a `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker`. This will allow the `Window` to respond to user interaction and render while your task progresses.