# WPF Application exit code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to set and get the application exit code .

I am trying to do something following :

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    if ( e.Args.Length != 0)
    {


    }
    else
    {
        new MainWindow().ShowDialog();
    }
    Environment.ExitCode = 110;
    this.Shutdown();
}
```

And then I am trying in `cmd` to get it by `echo %ERRORLEVEL%`

But I get always result `0` , any idea what is the issue ?

Comment: try out `ERRORLEVEL` without percent sign

Comment: @sll , this way i get result ERRORLEVEL

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For WPF, try

```
Application.Current.Shutdown(110);
```

Note that the application needs to be running as a console app. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160587/no-output-to-console-from-a-wpf-application/160597#160597) is the easiest way I know of; the accepted answer looks more difficult.

An easy test to tell if you're running in console mode: call your app from the command line (make sure your code doesn't shut down right away). The main window should be showing. If you can type another command in the console, your app is not running in its context. The command prompt should be locked, waiting for you to close the window.

Comment: Be careful when testing this from within Visual Studio as the exit code will be 0 since it comes from the debugging host process. I didn't have to change to console app at all, my WPF win app is returning correct exit codes directly.

Comment: http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-system-error-codes-exit-codes-description

why is it 110?

Comment: @Idan that value came from the question. You should use whatever value is appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in `Main` method. Just change its return-value-type to `int` instead of `void` and return your `exit-code`

```
static int Main(string[] args) {
    // something to do
    Console.ReadKey();
    return 110;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To create a custom `Main` in WPF application, you should follow these steps:

- First: unload the project by right-click on it in Solution Explorer
  and click on *Unload Project*
- Modify the `.csproj` file by change the `<ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">` to this one: `<Page Include="App.xaml">`
- Now you can create your own `Main` method in your project:

*Sample `Main` method and `App` class:*

```
public partial class App : Application {

    [STAThread]
    public static int Main() {
        App app = new App();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        var i = app.Run();
        return i;
    }

    public App() : base() { }

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e) {
        e.ApplicationExitCode = 110;
        base.OnExit(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's WPF  so i don't have main

Comment: @Mark I tried this and got `**110**`! It's might you do something wrong, and so I can't understand why did you vote the answer down?!

Comment: @Javad_Amiry: Sorry it was my error. I was testing it from within Visual Studio and thus the debugger host process was interfering with my tests... I've removed the wrong comment but can apparently only remove the down vote if you edit the question, sorry. Thanks a lot for your suggested solution.

Answer (score 2):

override the OnExit method, and in the ExitEventArgs you can set that value.

```
 protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
 {
      e.ApplicationExitCode = your_value;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It works for me with either method (`Environment.ExitCode=110` or `Environment.Exit(110)`). I hope you are calling the program from the console and not from Visual Studio to then check the ExitCode...

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
Environment.Exit(110);
```

This will terminate the current application with exit code `110`.

Comment: I think he needs to set the exit code and then call ShutDown. If he does what you say, ShutDown won't be called.

Comment: -1 that is not the issue. Both methods yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the following ways...

> ```
>         Application.Current.Shutdown(110);
>         Environment.Exit(10);
>         this.Close();
> ```

Shoutdown() returns a code. and Exit() also returns an exit code, but Close() only closes the application.