# Return int from Main() in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I've a WPF application which takes one command line argument. I'm calling this application from command window

```
E:\Kushal Ramesh\Projects\XMLToImage\bin\Debug>XMLToImage.exe TEST1
```

In my WPF app I'm able to read the arguments using

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

If the work gets completed as expected I've to send a positive response. I'm setting ExitCode of process to 1 in my WPF app

```
Environment.ExitCode = 1;
```

but my console window doesn't show any response!

Am I missing something here? Is there any other way of calling an exe from command window to receive response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `Shutdown()` function:

```
Application.Current.Shutdown(1);
```

There is an alternative, but more complex solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7772088/1093508).

Comment: Thanks David. This is the correct answer.