# Is there any way to show output during update-database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm running a fairly large seed as a stress test, and I'm wondering if it's possible to show output to a console.

I'd like to show the remaining entries or percent complete, or anything really.

Is there a way to write to the console or package manager console during update-database?

Comment: Your application output type is a Library or Console?

Comment: My application is a library.

Comment: Just interesting, did you managed to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to write to the console or package manager console
>   during update-database?

**I will describe two options which are available for you out of the box:**

**1. `Console.WriteLine` Solution:**

Either if you're running your code from a **Console** application or from a **Library** of any other application type (e.g. asp.net), you can use the `Console.WriteLine` function, but the main question is if there is a *listener* to the `Console` output.

If nothing is listening to the Console, then take advantage of the **`Win32.AllocConsole()`** Windows APIs function in order to open a ***listener***:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[DllImport("kernel32")]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

**Usage:**

```
AllocConsole();
//now you can call: Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Total number of records left to seed:{0}", total);
```

Consider to wrap the above code with the following directive in order to avoid of painful surprises in the production environment:

```
#if DEBUG

#endif
```

**Explanation:**

> AllocConsole initializes standard input, standard output, and standard
>   error handles for the new console. The standard input handle is a
>   handle to the console's input buffer, and the standard output and
>   standard error handles are handles to the console's screen buffer. To
>   retrieve these handles, use the GetStdHandle function.

**2. `Debug.Print` Solution:**

Use the `Debug.Print` function on debug mode. Using it, you would be able to write whatever you want to the DEBUG output window of Visual Studio:

**Debug -> Windows -> Output -> Show output from -> Debug**

By the way, did you consider logging this information using [NLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog) or [LOG4NET](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) to some text file, for instance?

Comment: What do you mean by listening? I've tried running Console.WriteLine, however nothing appears when I run the seed from update-database.

Comment: **listening**: You are writing to the Console, but the question if there is some open Console window to show your writes.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you!

If anyone else is looking to do this in WPF like I was, check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160587/no-output-to-console-from-a-wpf-application)

Answer (score 4):

if i understand you right, you need to add flag '-Verbose' to update-database command:

```
update-database -Verbose
```

Comment: `Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.`

Comment: how to save this output in a file

Comment: It is actually --verbose

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a hackish solution using EF 6.0 Interception if you can run your updates from a custom application.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DatabaseEntities, Configuration>());
        using (var entities = new DatabaseEntities())
        {
            entities.Database.Initialize(true);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    public class ProgressInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
    {
        private int currentRecord = 0;
        public int TotalCount { get; set; }

        public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
        }

        public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
        }

        public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Progress {0:P}", ++currentRecord / (double)TotalCount);
        }

        public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
        }

        public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
        }

        public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Seed Method:

```
protected override void Seed(EfProgress.DatabaseEntities context)
{
    var interceptor = new EfProgress.Program.ProgressInterceptor() { TotalCount = 10 };
    DbInterception.Add(interceptor);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var entity = context.EntitySet.Create();
        entity.Property1 = "entity " + i;
        context.EntitySet.Add(entity);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();

    DbInterception.Remove(interceptor);
}
```