# Is it possible to have a WPF application print console output?

Tags: c#, wpf, console

I have a simple WPF application. Under normal use, App.xaml will launch MainWindow.xaml. But I would like to set it up so that if it is invoked with a special command line argument, that it will function as a console application instead.

So here's roughly what my App.xaml.cs file looks like:

```
using System;

namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Args.Length == 1 && e.Args[0].Equals("/console"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("this is a test");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                mainWindow.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect that when I run `MyProject.exe /console` from the command line, it would print the string "this is a test". But right now it doesn't print anything. How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We have special class for this purpose:

```
internal static class ConsoleAllocator
{
    [DllImport(@"kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();

    [DllImport(@"kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport(@"user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    const int SwHide = 0;
    const int SwShow = 5;


    public static void ShowConsoleWindow()
    {
        var handle = GetConsoleWindow();

        if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            AllocConsole();
        }
        else
        {
            ShowWindow(handle, SwShow);
        }
    }

    public static void HideConsoleWindow()
    {
        var handle = GetConsoleWindow();

        ShowWindow(handle, SwHide);
    }
}
```

Just call `ConsoleAllocator.ShowConsoleWindow()` and then write to Console

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want the Application object to be created then you should create a separate class containing a Main entry point:

```
class Startup
{
    [STAThreadAttribute]
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            // run windowed
            App app = new App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
        }
        else
        {
            // run console
            ConsoleManager.Show();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

You'll also need to go into your application settings and change "Startup object" to "YourProjectNamespace.Startup", see [this article](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/09/how_to_write_custom_main_metho.html) for more details.

The console functions I'm calling come from the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160587/no-output-to-console-from-a-wpf-application) which shows how to tap into the standard Console streams.