# WPF Visual Studio Debug - Console

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, debugging, console

Today I've ran into a strange thing while testing my WPF app. Visual Studio was in Debug mode. I've created a routed event handler method and wanted to test if the calling was being done correctly, so I put `Console.WriteLine("test");` into that method and I was expecting to see the output (the "test" word) in the Output window of the Visual Studio. There didn't appear anything, but I think it should have (tested later on by showing a MessageBox).

I thought it should have appeared, because before this, I was using `Console` class to display messages to the output window, and it did allways work. So it quite surprise me, because this exact thing worked for me beforehand!

I found a "sollution", switching the project setting "Output type" to "Console App", but, as I expected, a Consolle appeared on the start of the application.

Could anyone please explain me how does the `Console` methods work in wpf apps in the default setting, and possibly what to use for the correct behaviour in the debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use the System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(); The output will display in the output window inside of VS directly.

Of course, you could also create a Console window manually before you actually call any Console.Write methods:

[No output to console from a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160587/no-output-to-console-from-a-wpf-application)

Comment: @Krepsy 3, What about this issue? Do you will use console window manually or  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()?

Answer (score 0):

Console.Writeline works fine in vs2017, not working in vs2019.
(tested by opening the same project in vs2017)