# WPF application command line arguments instead of starting GUI

Tags: wpf, command-line

I have WPF application and I want to add the option to do my stuff on the command line instead of opening the GUI.

Is there a way to get the command line arguments in my application and in case there are arguments continue without opening the GUI?

Comment: Can't the `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` be used at any time during the execution to retrieve the command line? [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=net-8.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could edit the `App.xaml.cs` file and override the `OnStartup` method:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] args = e.Args;
        if(args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "cl")
        {
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            Window2 mainWindow = new Window2();
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

You should also remove the `StartupUri` attribute from `<Application>` root element of the `App.xaml` file.

But if you want to be able to write to the console you need to create a console window manually:

[No output to console from a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160587/no-output-to-console-from-a-wpf-application)

Then you might as well create a console application in Visual Studio and instead start your WPF application based on the command line argument(s), e.g.:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 0 || args[0] != "cl")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\yourWpfApp.exe");
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

A console application is not a WPF application and vice versa. So create two different applications.

Answer (score 1):

In your `App.xaml.cs` implement the `OnStartup` method. So you can access the arguments passed via command line.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var args = e.Args;
    // do anything with arguments
}
```